# sizeof(z+100),for z of char type

Tags: c, sizeof

I test the following code:

```
char ch,z=120;
int x=5;
double y=7.5;
printf("\nsize of (z+100): %d" , sizeof(z+100));
```

The output I get is :

```
size of (z+100): 4
```

Can someone explain me this result?
I thought that the output had to be

```
size of (z+100): 1
```

Because tha range of char is 0...255,and 100 =120 is in range ...
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `z + 100` is an addition with arithmetic operands of type `char` and `int` (the numeric literal `100` is considered an integer in C).

The rules of the language stipulate that the result of such an arithmetic addition is also of type `int`, and `sizeof(int) == 4` (at least under your current compiler).

Comment: Wrong. It's adding an `int` (or `unsigned int`) to another `int`. `char` gets promoted to `int`, as @VladLazarenko said.

Comment: @ninjalj: The expression is in fact an addition of `char` to `int`. This is handled by the compiler by promoting the `char` to `int` as per the standard, but a) the standard itself says that the two operands must have *arithmetic type* (not `int`!) and b) this is not as central to the discussion as the fact that the *result* of the operation is an `int`. We don't disagree anywhere, but I think it's a bit harsh to say that my downplaying the less important (to non-standard buffs) part is "wrong". Teaching people is *all* about concentrating on the important stuff.

Comment: But the fact is that even `sizeof(z+z)` would have given the same result. So in that sense `100` being an `int` is not so important. The important stuff here is that the result of arithmetic with types that are narrower than `int` results in `int`.

Comment: @JensGustedt: I just looked that up to make extra sure, and you are right. Reworked the answer a bit to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

> A sizeof expression evaluates to an unsigned `size_t` value equal to
>   the size in bytes of the "argument" datatype, variable, or expression
>   (with datatypes, sizeof evaluates to the size of the datatype; for
>   variables and expressions it evaluates to the size of the type of the
>   variable or expression).

Since you have an expression with `char` and `int`, compiler converts `char` into `int` by integral promotion, thus `sizeof` operator will give you size of type `int`, which in your case is 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is converting it to an `int`, which would explain the size being 4 rather than 1.

Answer (score 0):

I guess

```
sizeof(z + 100);
```

results in an implicit cast to int, which has a size of four bytes.